# Google maps V2 android not working except in default or normal mode

Tags: android, google-maps

i am working for an app using google maps API V2 and everything is working normally till now, when, having quite finished the job, i decided to give the user the possibility to change the mode (from normal that i have used before and successfully) to the satellite one, adding only "googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);" to my code: and in this mode, i get not any map, only blank screen with my markers and so on. Not any warning in the log. All permissions allowed (and if this was the problem i think that i could not get maps from the normal mode...!) - Tried also the other modes, hybrid & terrain:: same result, blank screen... Some hint about that??? Thanks in advance.
osX 10.6.8
device sony Xperia Z.

Comment: any error you get from the logcat?

Comment: @ztan no, not any error in the log; strange!

Comment: found that changing (manually) the mode in the standard maps application from google in the phone results that satellite works in my app. But that means that my app cannot toggle between modes...